# Order status is not changing to processing even if successful online transaction

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, transaction

I am using CCAvenue Payment Gateway which is developed by BlueZeal. Sometimes the order status not changing to **Processing** keep shown **Pending**. I asked both teams they replied me, pls check with Magento Team.

May I know what are all possibilities for order status keep shown **Pending** even if successful Paid.

> Note: Not for every order,  two or three per month.

Comment: Please enable debug & error log , check request & response for this order particular why this happen because both of side working well in but some time its getting issue.

Comment: have you found any resolution for the same? We are having same issue, several orders stays pending... we are also using BlueZeal extension for CCAvenue

Comment: In my case, first time successful transaction is changed to processing, supposed if the transaction response late from bank server to respond Magento it's getting pending, here the point is session, if session out even successful transaction Magento shows pending so you manually check with ccavenue wheather the transaction really successful or not. This is bug, still we check pending transactions on ccavenue portal. I hope my explanation helpful, any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

CCavenue payment module configuration is reason for this :

If customer paid the money successfully, then it will show the status as "Processing" if not then it will show "Pending". You can make cross check whether customer made the payment or not in CCavenue dashboard.....

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right but the issue is customer bank end and CCAvenue server, sometimes the payment successful but CCAvenue Server struggle to get the second time response from bank end.. Actually the first time response from bank end its okay,, sometimes bank server or CCAvenue server coordination error.. This is what CCAvenue Persons told me.

Comment: @zus that's great, you can tell the same to client......

Comment: I have one more error, i can't able to delete one of my attributes values, could you pls help me that

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/201851/57334